# CORS Origin header

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to check if the Origin header is set in the client's request. At the moment the first if statement is what i'm trying to do but it doesn't work. How can this be fixed?

```
 const http = require('http');
 const port = 3000;

 http.createServer((req, res) => {
    headers = {
       'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
       'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, HEAD',
       'Access-Control-Max-Age': '7200'       

   };

   if (req.headers['ORIGIN'] === null) {
       res.statusCode = 400;
       res.end("Origin header not in the request")
   }

   if (req.method === 'HEAD') {
       res.writeHead(200, headers);
    res.end();
   }
   if (req.method === 'GET') {
       res.writeHead(200, headers);
       res.end("I was requested using CORS!");
   }

   if (req.method === 'POST') {
       res.writeHead(200, req.headers);
       res.end("I was requested using CORS!");
   }
   if (req.method =! 'GET' && req.method != 'POST' && req.method != 'HEAD'){
       res.writeHead(405, headers);
       res.end("Request used a HTTP method which is not allowed.");
   }
}).listen(port);
```

Comment: `if (req.method =! 'GET' && req.method != 'POST' && req.method != 'HEAD'){` is going to block a preflight OPTIONS request which makes setting `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` pointless.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

HTTP headers are case insensitive. From [RFC 2616 Section 4.2](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2):

> Each header field consists of a name followed by a colon (":") and the field value. Field names are case-insensitive.

For this reason, NodeJS's HTTP module will convert all header names to lowercase.  That being said, you can access the raw header names via [req.rawHeaders](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http_message_rawheaders).

To make your code work, I would check for a lowercase `origin` header, and I would also check if its value is `undefined` rather than `null` because if a header does not exist in a request its value will be `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Headers that don't exist will be `undefined`, not `null`.

That isn't a very useful check though. It just stops people visiting the URL directly in a browser, or from making a *same origin* request with JS. It won't prevent them from using other tools to make HTTP requests.